# How can I create a tile layout in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 for my site, where I have numerous posts. Right now I am using bootstrap columns and panels to display the posts on an index page.

But I want to show the same posts in a tile view like a Pinterest page.

Is there any way to do that in bootstrap 3? Right now my layout looks something like

```
<div class="row product-list">
    <?php getList(); ?>
</div>
```

where the function gets the list of posts.
and they are displayed in a panel like this:

```
<a href="product-des.php?1">
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3'><div class='panel panel-warning'>
<div class='panel-heading'>Microsoft Lumia 575</div>
<div class='panel-body'>
<img class='product_listing_img img-responsive' src=files/uploaded_images/mobile-2.jpg></div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

Current view

[image: What it looks like now using panels]

Expected view

[image: What I'd like it to look like (Pinterest style)]

Comment: Please show us the current output and expected output screenshot.

Comment: @ManojKumar i have updated my post please check

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your posts are of same height then you can use the `col-md-*` classes for the tiles wrapped inside a `row`. Each row will have posts based on the number of posts you want.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Title Test</div>
</div>
```

If the posts are of variable height then I will suggest you to use a plugin like [`masonry`](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

See the example here for dynamic height tiles : http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html#imagesloaded

**A basic example using CSS**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tQANc/590/

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height:100px;
    background:#BFBFBF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="cols">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but I came across this when searching for the same problem, so posting an answer for others who come across this.

Add **Bootstrap v4** and use the Cards functionality, http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

A note on backwards compatability, when just using v4 and not v3, this broke a lot of layouts when I was testing. So to use the Cards functionality without having to rework a lot of your layouts, add the CSS file to your page so you're using v3 and v4 alongside each other. Make sure v4 is first and v3 is last on the page in that order so that v3 takes priority when the browser loads these in.

Comment: Specifically, [`.card-columns`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#card-columns) is what gets the job done.